# Python-docx unable to use existing document - no style with name 'Title'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I'm trying to make a program that will create a document based on a text file and so far, it's worked fine. I decided that, to make it easier to use images and other things not supported/difficult to use effectively in Python-docx. Upon using exactly the same code but instead using Doc = document() I use Doc = document("template.docx"). After modifying, the file is saved to a different docx file. I get these errors when trying to use the template. There are no errors when creating a new document.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\Desktop\QPA.py", line 45, in <module>
    Doc.add_heading("QuizPax 28/02/2019",0)
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 39, in add_heading
    return self.add_paragraph(text, style)
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 56, in add_paragraph
    return self._body.add_paragraph(text, style)
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\blkcntnr.py", line 39, in add_paragraph
    paragraph.style = style
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\text\paragraph.py", line 111, in style
    style_or_name, WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 78, in get_style_id
    return self.styles.get_style_id(style_or_name, style_type)
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 109, in get_style_id
    return self._get_style_id_from_name(style_or_name, style_type)
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 139, in _get_style_id_from_name
    return self._get_style_id_from_style(self[style_name], style_type)
  File "C:\Users\bgrif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 53, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("no style with name '%s'" % key)
KeyError: "no style with name 'Title'"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Edit your `template.docx` file to add the `Title` style:

1. Open the file and create a new paragraph by hitting Enter
2. Select that paragraph and assign it the paragraph style `Title`.
3. Delete that paragraph
4. Save the file and try your code again.

In Word, a large number of pre-defined paragraph styles appear in the style gallery and pick-lists. The attributes of these styles are known to the Word application, but Word does not actually store any of these styles in the document until they are first used. After that, they stay with that document even when not used by any content.

`python-docx` can only work with the styles that are defined *in the document*, so you need to add that style into your template document to use it, which the `.add_heading(.., 0)` call does.

Answer (score 0):

Just as stated by Scanny, `python-docx` can **ONLY** work with styles that are defined in the document.

You can **CHECK** if your document has the styles (e.g. 'Title') you require by printing to console.

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document("template.docx")
for style in doc.styles:
    print("style.name == %s" % style.name)
```

If your styles do not exist, you can add them **programmatically**:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

doc = Document("template.docx")

styles = doc.styles
styles.add_style('Title', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH) # styles added here
styles.add_style('List Number', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
styles.add_style('List Bullet', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
# ... any other styles

doc.save("new_template.docx")
```

**OR** (If you are writing to the file):

```
paragraph = doc.add_paragraph(style='Title')
doc.save("new_template.docx")
```

Using `python-docx` version `1.1.0`. Read more from [python-docx Documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html).